# Django: admin.site.register issue

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I am using django-simple-history https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html for managing my site history and django-ajax-select https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects in my web app. The problem I am facing is in the admin register part. Initially when I was just using django-ajax-select my admin.py would be like

```
class DeviceAdmin(AjaxSelectAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
    models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 6, 'cols': 50})},
}
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'Tag_ID', 'IMEI', 'Device_Name', 'Location', 'Employee_Name_Owner')
    list_filter = ('Location__Location', 'Device_Name', 'Manufacturer__Manufacturer', 'Phone_Carrier__Phone_Carrier',
               'Device_Type__Device_Type', 'Service_Status__Service_Status', 'Purchase_Date', 'Created_At',
               'Updated_At')
    search_fields = ('Tag_ID', 'IMEI', 'Phone_Number', 'MEID_HEX', 'MEID_DEC', 'Device_Name', 'Serial_Number',
                 'Employee_Name_Owner__Email')
admin.site.register(Device,DeviceAdmin)
```

But now when I try to use django-sipmle-history according to its doc I have to use admin.site.register like

```
admin.site.register(Device, SimpleHistoryAdmin)
```

Finally because of using **SimpleHistoryAdmin** in **admin.site.register** I loose all the functionalities of my **DeviceAdmin** class. I need a way to use **DeviceAdmin** and **SimpleHistory Admin** together.

PS: Apologizes for any duplicacy or asking a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you basically want your the admin page for `Device` to extend both `DeviceAdmin` and `SimpleHistoryAdmin` so you get functionality of both.

Try the following:

```
class DeviceAdmin(AjaxSelectAdmin):
    ... code that you have above ...

class DeviceAdminWithHistory(DeviceAdmin, SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Device, DeviceAdminWithHistory)
```

There's a chance that the two classes `DeviceAdmin` and `SimpleHistoryAdmin` might have overlapping fields or methods. But after looking at the source for [SimpleHistoryAdmin](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history/blob/master/simple_history/admin.py#L30) and [AjaxSelectAdmin](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects/blob/develop/ajax_select/admin.py), it looks like the above should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Some how I was trying the same thing but I guess I was defining the classes incorrectly. Appreciate your help.

Comment: just exactly what I was looking for. Thanks